# firebase sign up with additional details for authentication

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am creating sign up page with firebase so i want to users firstname and lastname we can do with real time database but i do not understand how to do with exact uid as user sign up uid using set keyword can you please guide me to create this.

Here is code snippet i am trying
[image]

Comment: please don't post image of your code, post the code as text inside your answer. use the format button  `{}`

Comment: Do you just want to add first and last name to the user? if so, Firebase Auth provides an updateProfile API to set the user's display name and photo URL. If you have additional information to set, database would be the right way to go.